# Visual Studio - How to find which solution a source file is part of?

Tags: visual-studio

I'm working ona  project containing thousands of solutions (.sln) and tens of thousands of .cs/.cpp/etc files.

How can i find which solution(s) a source file is a part of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Source files aren't part of a solution.  They are part of a project, which in turn is part of a solution.  The source file itself has no notion of being part of the project though.  The project has a reference to the file but not the other way around.  One source file can be part of multiple projects, which might be part of different solutions.

What you could do is parse the SLN and VBPROJ/CSPROJ/whatever files to see which ones refer to a particular source file.  Those files are just text and contain various information about the solution or project, including what projects are part of a solution and what files are part of a project.  You could recursively parse the files in folder to build up an entire tree representing the files in the projects in the solutions.

Note that most files are going to be referred to by relative paths in the project file.

Comment: ok, I found out a way using the LOCATE32 tool which is freely available. (windows search would work too)

1. Search all *.csproj Containing text "SourceFileName.cs"
2. You will find the project(s) that the file is part of.
3. Search all SLN files that contain "ProjectNameFoundInStep2.csproj"
4. You will get all solutions

Answer (score 0):

Start with [Visual Commander](http://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) and then you can programmatically access your solution "DOM-style" using Visual Studio's [Automation and Extensibility for Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc52cke4.aspx) API.  Write a  VS command in a .NET language that traverses a solution into its projects and then into the project items, dumping all files found (project items) into a log file, database, web service, what have you.

See e.g., this article [HOWTO: Navigate the files of a solution from a Visual Studio .NET macro or add-in](http://www.mztools.com/articles/2014/MZ2014007.aspx) on how to navigate Visual Studio's DTE.

I know SO frowns on answers containing just links and not true help, but the documentation for EnvDTE in its various flavors is extensive and any code sample to demonstrate how to use it would be quite large.  So I'm just giving you this strong hint: Look at the Visual Studio extensibility model, and hook into it easily via Visual Commander which does all the hard work of wrapping your code in a Visual Studio extension.  From there you can use any reasonable technique (MSBuild, PowerShell, batch files) to load each solution into VS and run your new command.

This actually answers the question:  For all source files used by any of my thousands of solutions, which solutions use them.  But I see that you (@Sabz), below in a comment, give a reasonable way to answer the question for one source file at a time, which is more precisely what you asked.

N.B.: I have not (yet) used Visual Commander so I'm just assuming it works as advertised.